# Unable to import arcpy into Spyder with ArcGIS Pro 2.7

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, spyder

I am trying to import arcpy into Spyder. I saw  [ArcPy import arcgiscripting](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/375399/176848)  relating to this, but I'm using ArcGIS Pro 2.7, not ArcMap. My original Python is 3.8 but for the environment that I created to run arcpy in Spyder, I installed Python 3.6 (following an error I got previously). This is similar to what was suggested at [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/344029/176848) to [Importing arcpy in Spyder](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/176879/115), but when I install Spyder on the newly-created anaconda environment, I try to import arcpy into Spyder and get the following error:

```
 File "C:\Users\anner\AppData\Local\Programs\ArcGIS\Pro\Resources\ArcPy\arcpy\geoprocessing\_base.py", line 14, in <module>
    import arcgisscripting

ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.
```

I've tried updating the Python interpreter in Spyder to the python.exe that was automatically installed with ArcGIS but got this message

[image]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are using the wrong version of Spyder.

I created a tutorial on [Installing spyder IDE for ArcPro [sic]](https://community.esri.com/t5/arcgis-pro-blog/installing-spyder-ide-for-arcpro/ba-p/901923) at GeoNet that you can try to follow to accomplish this.